# Github API for retrieving organization activities

Tags: github, github-api

We found below link which can get organization events for authenticated user:
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/activity/events#list-organization-events-for-the-authenticated-user

```
curl \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>" \
  https://api.github.com/users/USERNAME/events/orgs/ORG
```

However, it seems only limited (1 day?) events are returned, are there ways to return org events for longer period, e.g, 30 days?